# How to delete an item in react

Tags: reactjs

I have opened the dialogue box on the delete button and when ok is pressed `deleteFruit` is called, id is passed to it.

```
function fruits{
 let data = [{id:1, name:'grapes'},{id:2, name:'orange'}]
 const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false)
 const deleteFruit= (id) =>{alert(id)}

  function exampldata() {
    return ( {data.map(item ={
         return <button onClick={()=>setOpenDialog(true)}>Delete</button>
      })
   } 

 return (
    <>
       {exampldata()}

       <Dialog open={open}>       
        <Button   onClick={handleClose} > Cancel</Button>
          <Button  onClick={deleteFruit}>Ok</Button>          
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog> 
   </>
 )
}
```

Comment: So... What's your problem? What are you trying to achieve? What's happening here ? You should try to give out more detail, if we have to spend a while just to read your code to understand, maybe, all of that, you won't get a lot of answers

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter the `data` based on the `id` you have passed. And that will remove the `item` you want to remove.

But make sure you keep your `data` in a `state` variable so that your view re-renders when you update it using `setData`.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([{id:1, name:'grapes'},{id:2, name:'orange'}]);

 const deleteFruit= (id) =>{           
   const tempData = data.filter(item => item.id !== id); // this will remove the item which matches the id
   setData(tempData);
 }
```

Comment: You can't reassign `data` since it's `const`. Just use `setData(data.filter(...))`

Comment: @HaoWu sorry dude missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain state for delete ids. Add to set when deleted and filter the deleted items while render.

```
function fruits() {
  let data = [
    { id: 1, name: "grapes" },
    { id: 2, name: "orange" },
  ];
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(new Set());
  const deleteFruit = (id) => {
    setDeleted(deleted.add(id));
  };

  function exampldata() {
    return (
      <div>
        {data
          .filter((item) => !deleted.has(item.id))
          .map((item) => (
            <button onClick={() => setOpenDialog(true)}>Delete</button>
          ))}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {exampldata()}

      <Dialog open={open}>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}> Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick={deleteFruit}>Ok</Button>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```